# Excluding cateory not working on my site. how to solve this?

Tags: categories, exclude

I am using my own wordpress theme.

I am trying to exclude some categories on my `author.php`

I am using the following code for that purpose.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
$args = array('author'=> $author_id, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'category__not_in' => 16, 19, 1, 20);
query_posts( $args); ?>
```

I tried 
`$args = array('author'=> $author_id, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'cat' => -16, -19, -1, -20);` also not working.

How can I exclude those four categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your ids in an array.

```
$args = array('author'=> $author_id, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'category__not_in' => array( 16, 19, 1, 20 ) );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: thanks for that.. its working now after I've wrapped it.. I forgot that..